# Flex Data binding on an mx component's property

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, flex4

Getting a warning from the compiler that data binding won't see assignments to "cmRepeater"

```
<mx:Repeater id="cmRepeater">
    <support:CancelMembershipRowSelector lineItem="{cmRepeater.currentItem}" selectedTicketsOBJ="{selectedTicketsCancel}" />
</mx:Repeater>
```

Also getting that it can't see assignments to "TICKETS" here where deRep is a repeater and the currentItem will be an XML object.

```
dataProvider="{deRep.currentItem.TICKETS.TICKET}"  itemClick="viewCharacs(event);">
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will work if you try to bind to an XML object or property directly but it might work if you convert your data to an ArrayCollection, something like

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Model id="myXML" source="../assets/myXML.xml"/>
    <s:ArrayCollection id="myArrayCollection" source="{myXML.myNode}"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<mx:Repeater id="cmRepeater" dataProvider={myArrayCollection}>
     <support:CancelMembershipRowSelector lineItem="{cmRepeater.currentItem}" selectedTicketsOBJ="{selectedTicketsCancel}" />
</mx:Repeater>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's basically how this is working. There is also a code-behind for the component containing the Repeater component. And in it there is a variable that holds an XMLListCollection that is set as the Repeater's dataprovider

Answer (score 0):

Apparently cmRepeater had not been marked as Bindable. I marked it as Bindable and now I don't get the warning.